# Display mysql table in HTML, merge all rows that has same values in second column

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the below php code that displays mysql table as html table. Mysql table contains 4 columns : date, id, item, quantity.

While displaying in html table I want to merge all the rows that has same "id" in 2nd column.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if ($result==True) 
{   
    echo "<table border='3' style='position:absolute;width:60%;top:20px;left:20%;text-align:center;border-collapse: collapse;'>";

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Date</th>";
        echo "<th>id</th>";
        echo "<th>item</th>";
        echo "<th>quantity</th>";       
    echo "</tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";            
            echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
            echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
            echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
            echo "<td>$row[4]</td>";            
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    mysqli_close($db);
}
```

My table in Mysql looks like below:

```
    Date         Id     Item    Quantity
    1/1/2015    12345   Apple   1 KG
    1/1/2015    12345   Apple   1 KG
    1/1/2015    12345   Apple   1 KG
    1/1/2015    97786   Apple   1 KG
    1/1/2015    76767   Apple   1 KG
    1/1/2015    24335   Apple   1 KG
    1/1/2015    9098    Apple   1 KG
```

I want my html table to look like below:
(rows 1, 2 and 3 are merged because it has same id)

```
    Date         Id     Item    Quantity
    1/1/2015            Apple   1 KG
    1/1/2015    12345   Carrot  1 KG
    1/1/2015            Onion   1 KG
    1/1/2015    97786   Apple   1 KG
    1/1/2015    76767   Apple   1 KG
    1/1/2015    24335   Apple   1 KG
    1/1/2015    9098    Apple   1 KG
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting the question.

Comment: Look into using a <td>s rowspan attribute [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#Attributes)

Comment: I don't think you can do this in one pass through the recordset as what you need to do is apply a `rowspan` attribute with appropriate count to the `TD` in the second column. IMO this would require 2 passes through the recordset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display mysql table in HTML, merge all rows that has same values in 2nd column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068414/display-mysql-table-in-html-merge-all-rows-that-has-same-values-in-2nd-column)

Answer (score 0):

As it does not seems to be best solution , but it should work ..try

```
$check=array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {
      if(in_array($row[2],$check)
        $row[2]="";
        echo "<tr>";            
            echo "<td>$row[1]</td>";
            echo "<td>$row[2]</td>";
            echo "<td>$row[3]</td>";
            echo "<td>$row[4]</td>";            
        echo "</tr>";
        $check[]=$row[2];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have updated my answer. Please see it and try


//Set all value in some temp array 
$array_date = "";
$array_id = "";
$array_item = "";
$array_qty = "";
$array_rowspan = "";

$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{


    if($tempid != $row[1]){

        $tempid = $row[1];
        $rowspan = 1;       
        $array_date[] = $row[0]; 
        $array_id[] = $row[1];
        $array_item[] = $row[2];
        $array_qty[] = $row[3];         
        $array_rowspan[$i] = $rowspan;

        //Set another temp value to set same rowspan in mached category id  
        $same_id=1; 
    }else{

        $rowspan++;     
        $array_date[] = $row[0];
        $array_id[] = $row[1];
        $array_item[] = $row[2];
        $array_qty[] = $row[3];

        //Set another temp value to set same rowspan in mached category id          
        $same_id++;     
        for($j=0; $j<$same_id; $j++){
            $array_rowspan[$i-($j)] = $rowspan;
        }

    }       

    $i++;   

}

echo "<table border='1' style='position:absolute;width:60%;top:20px;left:20%;text-align:center;border-collapse: collapse;'>";

    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Date</th>";
        echo "<th>id</th>";
        echo "<th>item</th>";
        echo "<th>quantity</th>";       
     echo "</tr>";
    //Set a temp variable like for id
    $tempid2 = "";
    foreach($array_id as $key => $val){

        if($tempid2 != $val){
            $tempid2 = $val;
            echo "<tr>"; 
            echo "<td>".$array_date[$key]."</td>";
            echo "<td rowspan='".$array_rowspan[$key]."'>".$array_id[$key]."</td>";     
            echo "<td>".$array_item[$key]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$array_qty[$key]."</td>"; 
            echo "</tr>";
        }else{
            echo "<tr>"; 
            echo "<td>".$array_date[$key]."</td>";              
            echo "<td>".$array_item[$key]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$array_qty[$key]."</td>"; 
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }

 echo "</table>";
```

Please try this

Comment: This will print the first id and if next id is same as first then it will print nothing. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind looping through the data an extra time (and a bit), you can do it using rowspan.

```
$table = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $table[$row[1]][] = array($row[0],$row[2],$row[3]);
}

echo "<table border='3' style='position:absolute;width:60%;top:20px;left:20%;text-align:center;border-collapse: collapse;'>";
echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Date</th>";
        echo "<th>id</th>";
        echo "<th>item</th>";
        echo "<th>quantity</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
foreach($table as $id=>$idRows) {
    $rowspan = count($idRows);
    for($i = 0; $i < $rowspan; $i++) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$idRows[$i][0]}</td>";
            if($i === 0)
                echo "<td rowspan={$rowspan}>{$id}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$idRows[$i][1]}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$idRows[$i][2]}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score -2):

Use group by with column name

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY `id`";
```

Comment: If we do this, we will get only one row.

Comment: then try `$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY id, item";`